# Friend added friend in News Feed

Tags: facebook

Every now and then I see on my news feed that my friend, Annie, has added a new friend to her account—I don't see this news feed from my other friends. I am wondering, is this a setting that Annie has set on her account so all of her friends can see who he has added onto her account?

Is this a default setting? How would you modify this setting? In addition, can you target this so that only certain friends on your list will see in their news feed that you have added friends?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is all handled via Facebook newsfeed algorithm. Based on certain factors (which only Facebook internally knows), some of friends will show the "added friend" story in the feed while others do not.

Comment: Is there any way to block this action?

Comment: No, there is not.